# Ubuntu 13.10 partition not booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have dual booted my laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. On start up,it shows me boot menu. If I select Windows 7 it boots up normally and works fine. But when I select Ubuntu option, it shows me Ubuntu splash screen but doesn't get booted up i.e. doesn't show desktop. I have my important data on Ubuntu partition. Is there any way so that I can get into my Ubuntu and take up all my data files?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to grab files off of your Ubuntu filesystem from this dual booted laptop, and you only have access to Windows, there's a great little utility from DiskInternals that will allow Windows to open a Linux filesystem.

You can find it on this page:
http://www.diskinternals.com/download/

And then scroll down to find "Linux Reader" in the list of freeware products.

The utility will allow Windows read EXT-formatted partitions, and you can copy and save files from the partitions into your Windows partition.